# Bean Validation API / Hibernate Validator: any way to detect the requested validation groups during validation?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Indeed, this is somewhat a duplicate of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385256/bean-validation-get-validation-groups), however I was wondering whether, after nine years and some new specification versions being published, the situation has changed in any way, or whether at least a non portable way to solve this problem exists (I mean: does Hibernate Validator allow to do this, even if the API does not?).

The question is: is there a way I can make my custom constraint validator detect the validation groups that were passed to the validator instance causing the validation to occur, by inspecting the `ConstraintValidatorContext`?

Example, suppose I have my bean:

```java
public class MyBean {

  @MyConstraint(value = 5, groups = V1.class)
  @MyConstraint(value = 10, groups = {V2.class, V3.class})
  private int foo;

  // cut
}
```

and a validator call:

```java
validator.validateValue(MyBean.class, "foo", 7, V2.class);
```

can my constraint validator detect that `V2.class` validation group was requested, in this specific case?

```java
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, Integer> {

  // cut

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Class<?>[] requestedValidationGroups = // expected {V2.class} here, in case of the above call
  }
}
```

In the `initialize` method I can get an information about the static declaration of the constraint annotation, so in the above example I could get `{V1.class}` or `{V2.class, V3.class}` depending on which of the two constraints the implementation detects as the one being applied. However, I would need to get just `{V2.class}` in this case.

Is it possible in some way?

Looking at Hibernate Validator 6.0 sources, I see I would need access to `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValueContext<T, V>`, in particular its `currentGroup` property, but neither this group nor the `ValueContext` itself is passed to the Hibernate Validator constraint validator context implementation implementation  (`org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl`), whose creation, on the other hand, seems not to be customisable (there's a direct `new ConstraintValidatorContextImpl(...)` call in `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ValidationContext<T>, ValueContext<?, ?>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>)`).

Any further hint?